# Which scope must be used if we want the instance collected by the GC to be disposed properly?

Tags: ninject, named-scope

Must `InParentScope` be used if one wants an instance collected by GC to be Disposed properly ? If not which Scope should be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is not covered by https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes, I'll be happy to make any changes needed based on any follow-ups you have.

Comment: I may be wrong but last time i checked the wiki this info wasn't here or maybe ive mislooked. Anyway it is rather clear now. InParentScope seem to be the scope i need.

Comment: "The difference to InTransientScope is that bindings with this scope will be deactivated after the object that gets the instance injected is collected by the garbage collector." What mean bindings with this scope will be deactivated.. does that mean all future Get<> resolve won't work anymore if the instance created get disposed ?

Comment: @Rushino You're right - I only edited it in about a week back. Deactivated refers to a phase of processing in Ninject. If the object is Disposable, deactivation will mean running Dispose. It's the objects not the bindings that get deactivated so I'll fix that incorrect language - thanks for the catch. Remember that a deactivated object will no longer be referenced by Ninject (and hence no other `Get` will ever consider providing it (and as the object is Disposed it would be perfectly within its rights to throw an `ObjectDisposedException`). So you obv need to ensure nobody needs them anymore

Comment: @Remo can you review please? Updated: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki/InParentScope

Answer (score 2):

Objects any scope except `InTransientScope()` are disposed when the lifetime of the scope ends. There is no *correct* one as the scope defines how long an object lives and this depends on the concrete situation.

An object `InParentScope()` is `Dispose`d when the object it is injected into is either garbage collected or when it is deactivated by Ninject because its own scope has ended.

**Note that if the Scope of the Parent is `InTransientScope()`, the object will not be tracked, so use it with care.**

Comment: so its better not to use InTransientScope if i want my services objets correctly disposed ?